# Will replacing wall-mounted kitchen faucet help with leak?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I live in a 1930 building and have a wall-mounted faucet as shown in the first two pictures. I have had the cartridges under the handles replaced twice (the last time for $300), but a drip always returns, despite my efforts to tighten gently when turning off the water -- after the cartridge replacement the water shuts of with a light turn of handle and no drip, but after a short time it starts to feel maxed-out, and a tighter and tighter turn is needed to shut the water off fully, and eventually even a very tight turn won't stop the drip.

I'm wondering (a) if I can replace the faucet with one like that shown in the third picture (the nuts on the existing faucet, as shown in the close-up, are 8 inches from the horizontal center of one to the other), and (b) if this is likely to improve the drip situation. Obviously sinks all over the world have handles with variable flow strengths and you can shut them off without a drip. I'm just trying to understand whether, with these old-style faucets, I'm always going to have problems with cartridges getting maxed-out and having to be replaced. If it came to it, I'd even be happy with a non-variable on/off mechanism if that was required to stop the drip.

[image: Existing faucet]

[image: Existing faucet close-up]

[image: New faucet for $95]

Comment: $300 is a rip off, total rip off, a crime.

Comment: When you unscrew the top screw with a screw driver you can remove the handle. Now you see the valve body screwed in with a wrench. If you take it out (shut of water before), you will see a rubber seal at the end held with small screw in the middle. Now use a flash light and look at the surface inside where that rubber was sitting on. Is it clean and smooth ? Probably not, and there is where you leak comes from. Now unscrew the old valve assambly take it to the shop and get new one that would fit.

Comment: Get a replacement with the quarter turn taps which have ceramic internals - they last well.

Comment: @SolarMike, thanks for the tip. I'll check them out.

Comment: @Ruskes, thanks for the instructions. I didn't mention that this sink has no shut off valves. (Some ad hoc BS went on somewhere in the past 90 years.) So the manager has to turn off the water to the whole stack before I can unscrew the handles. That's why I don't do it myself, because each second is precious. In this case it was actually the manager and his brother who did the work. (In fairness the $300 included assessing what would need to be done to put in shut off valves. Answer: big money.) But anyway that's why I don't just open and fix/replace the cartridges/washers myself.

Comment: For those interested, this is a good video about the quarter-turn ceramic valves. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fU_81RyS48

Comment: @MKatz I understand your hesitation (but $300 hurts me), anyway, since they installed it and charged you $300 and it is still leaking CALL them back to fix it.

Comment: @Ruskes, yes, I've told the manager it's leaking again. Hopefully they will fix it again for free, or give me a discount on installing the new faucet.